# Counting arguments passed to scanf() in C

Tags: c, arrays, count, arguments, scanf

Is there any way to Count number of arguments passed to `scanf()` in C ? Specially, while assigning `int` arrays through `scanf()`. 
Example:

```
int array[1000], i;
for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
    scanf("%d",&array[i]);
```

I need to count how many values are inserted by user

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly it is you are trying to do?

Comment: `scanf` returns "the number of input items successfully matched and assigned." That's not quite what you asked, but it's probably close to what you want.

Comment: scanf automaticalyy returns number of variables assigned. so `int count=scanf("%d".&a)` will return 1 if a is successfully assigned. Similary you can use your statment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a built in way to do this, but why not just create a counter that increments when scanf returns successfully and break the loop otherwise?

```
int scanf_counter = 0;
int array[1000], i;

for(i=0;i<1000;i++) {

    if(scanf("%d",&array[i] > 0) {
        scanf_counter++;
    } else {
        break;
    }

}
```

Although I'm not sure I understand your question exactly because you could always just find the size of the array by doing this

```
int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])
```

Comment: I think I better understand what you want to do. Please check my edit. When scanf returns > 0, a value was successfully set and you can increment the counter. Otherwise, just break the loop and you should be left with the correct number of values set in scanf_counter after the loop breaks.

Comment: @user4577978 Please clarify what you are looking for. We cannot help you otherwise.

Comment: You're welcome, would you mind selecting my answer as the accepted answer as it seems to have helped you?

Comment: There should be a check mark to the left of my answer near the up and down arrows. If you click that, it should turn green and it will show my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Look the scanf() fragment carefully, thus:

## include

int main()

{
    double a[100000],mx=0;

```
int i,j,c=0;
printf("Enter as many numbers as you wish . Press Ctrl+D or any character to stop inputting :\n");  

for(i=0;i<100000;i++)

{
    if((scanf("%lf",&a[i]))==1)

        c++;

    //else break;

}

for(j=0;j<c;j++)

{
    if(a[j]>mx) mx=a[j];
}

printf("You have inserted %d values and the maximum is:%g",c,mx);


return 0;
```

}

Comment: 400000 bytes (100000*sizeof int) on the stack is a very bad idea.  Suggest placing the array in the file global address space

Comment: I see your having a similar problem as I do regarding placing $include <...> statements in an answer.  Does anyone know of a fix?